# Google setOnloadcallback() function clash with window.onload

Tags: javascript, api, onload

here is my code:

```
window.onload = function(){
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
    alert("Message");
  });
}
```

I know it will work if I put google load outside window.onload. But I want it to be inside the window.onload. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want it to be there if it doesn't work?

Comment: Why would you want to attach an event to the load event *after* the load events have fired?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the Google loader is using `document.write` to add scripts to the page. `document.write` only works before the window has fully loaded, so it seems you can't use `google.load` inside of `window.onload`. I'd recommend putting whatever code you need inside of the `google.setOnLoadCallback` function - `window.onload` works fine in there.

Alternatively, you can autoload the Google APIs so that the onLoadCallback is unnecessary like this (see docs for more info):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={modules:[{name:gdata,version:2.x,packages:[blogger]}]}"></script>
```

Also check out the jQuery library because it has functions like `$(document).ready()` that improve greatly on window.onload.